# Want to create super user (administrator) account?

Tags: login

Have installed ubuntu 13.04. While login, i am unable to login using user name and password.

So i am loging in by using guest account.

I need to create the admin account now. can any one help me .

I have also tried sudo su but it says, "Unable to change to sudoers gid :operation not permitted."

I have tried su also but when I enter the password it says, "Authentication failure".

Regards
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easy :

Use sudo. Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` and type in `sudo gnome-control-center` to open Ubuntu settings as a root user. Type in your current password when prompted

[image: Opening Settings in Sudo mode]

after that, go to the User accounts section and create your new account and set it as admin.

[image: User accounts].

After you're done..logout of your current account and login as admin, and you're done..:)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You can't use sudo from the guest account, and if you can do anything with sudo otherwise, you're already logged in with an administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the password reset method as in the link below

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword[enter link description here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)

If you want to get the user list type `cat /etc/passwd` and to reset the password type `passwd username`